# Video Picker - exception in Nougat

Tags: android

This is our code for video picker, pretty much standard code.  This code works in Android version before Nougat, however, it raises an exception in nougat.

```
private void pickVideoFromGallery(Activity activity){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MediaPicker.TYPE_FILEVIDEO);
}
```

And the exception is

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle 
Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] 
typ=video/* launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
```

However if I uncomment following line, it starts working but that's not the solution as we are looking to select only openable videos

```
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please stop adding the android tag to your question title.

Answer (score 0):

Launch default file picker with videos.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("video/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        galleryIntent.setType("video/*");
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser");
```